# When concurrently filing, should in include a copy of documents previously filed?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis

I previously files online an I-130, and I-130a. Now I'm going to file concurrently the I-485 and necessary other documents. When I send these to the USCIS lockbox and include the receipt that I filed the I-130a, should I send an *additional* copy of the I-130 and other evidence that I already filed?

Comment: What does the instructions say?

Comment: @littleadv nothing: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-485instr.pdf at least the i-485 instructions don't mention if you should resubmit the i-130 stuff you already sent.

Comment: So why are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the I-485, you only include the documents listed as required in the I-485 instructions. Since you are filing I-485 separately from I-130, you need to include a copy of the I-130 receipt, because it is required by the [I-485 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-485instr.pdf), What Evidence Must You Submit with Form I-485? #5. Documentation of Your Immigrant Category, which contains:

> If you are filing as a principal applicant and your immigrant category
> allows you to file Form I-485 before your petition is approved, you
> may submit your Form I-485 together with:
>
> A. Your immigrant petition; or
>
> B. A photocopy of Form I-797, Receipt Notice, for your immigrant
> petition.

A is for people who file I-130 an I-485 together. Since you filed I-130 first and I-485 later, you would include B, a copy of the I-130 receipt.

You do not need to include a copy of the actual I-130 form or any of the documents required by the I-130, unless they are also listed as required by the I-485 instructions.

Comment: So it's better not to send things that have already been sent so long as they're not required. Basically, more isn't better here.